# Jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, jasmine

i am new to jasmine and I need to write code coverage for following code :

```
spyOn(company.LoginData,'isUserLogged').and.returnValue(true);
```

how to cover the customerAddress and regionCode variables in jasmine test case ?

```
var regionCode = company.Utils.getRegionCodeFromMapping(company.regionFromPagePath.toUpperCase());
    // In case the user is logged in.
    if (company.LoginData.isUserLogged()) {
        var customer = company.LoginData.data.userProfile.customer;
        var customerAddress = !_.isUndefined(customer.address[0]) ? customer.address[0] : customer.address;
        regionCode = customerAddress.countryName.code;
    }
```

Comment: Are these private functions?

Comment: @Shyam Babu yes this code is part of a private function()